# Why does Android cut URL fragments from intents?

Tags: android, url, uri

When I register an app to handle http URLs, and have the following link target (tested using the contacts app):

```
http://simon#kullo.net
```

I receive an intent in my app that is missing everything starting from the hash:

```
Intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://simon/ flg=0x13400000 cmp=net.kullo.android/.screens.NewMessageActivity }
 Data: http://simon/
   scheme: http
   scheme specific part: //simon/
   encoded scheme specific part: //simon/
   fragment: null
   fragment encoded: null
 Extras: <none>
```

Even with a more real world example, the same thing happens:

```
http://example.com/#section2
```

Result:

```
Intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://example.com/ flg=0x13400000 cmp=net.kullo.android/.screens.NewMessageActivity }
  Data: http://example.com/
    scheme: http
    scheme specific part: //example.com/
    encoded scheme specific part: //example.com/
    fragment: null
    fragment encoded: null
  Extras: <none>
```

This happens in my own app as well as in the Browser I use to open the URL. Android 5.1 emulator.

Comment: "tested using the contacts app" -- how do you know that this isn't a problem with the Contacts app, then?

Comment: Because I have exactly the same effect in the Browser app. I need to use a custom URI scheme then to launch another app, because `http` is opened in the same browser tab.

Comment: [The source code to `Uri`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/net/Uri.java) suggests that `parse()` pays attention to the fragment. I suggest that you write some code that uses `Uri.parse()`, then examines whether you get your fragment. If you don't, then there's a bug in `Uri`, at least one some versions of Android. If you do get the fragment, though, then your problem lies in apps (Contacts, Browser, perhaps others) more so than with Android itself, I suspect.

Comment: The Uri object and Uri.parse work fine. I can also pass the Uri to an Intent within my app and all data stays in place. So it looks like a bug in other apps.